# Redux Form v6 - onSubmit function being called, but not dispatching an action

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs, redux, redux-form

I'm trying to setup a simple form using redux-form.

Right now I just have a button, that should dispatch an action. I see the `SET_SUBMIT_SUCCEEDED` action so I know the form submitted successfully, and I can see the `onSubmit` function I specified is being called, but it is not dispatching an action.

```
// root reducer
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { reducer as reduxFormReducer } from 'redux-form'
import login from './login'

export default combineReducers({
  login,
  form: reduxFormReducer
})


// action-creator
import { createAction } from './create_action'
import { postJson } from './fetch'
import {
  LOGIN_ERROR,
  LOGIN_REQUEST,
  LOGIN_SUCCESS
} from '../constants/constants'

const login = () => {
  return function (dispatch) {
    dispatch(createAction(LOGIN_REQUEST))
    return postJson('/login')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data =>
        dispatch(createAction(LOGIN_SUCCESS, { data }))
      )
      .catch(error => dispatch(createAction(LOGIN_ERROR, { error })))
  }
}


//component
import React from 'react'
import { reduxForm } from 'redux-form'
import login from '../redux/submit-handlers/login'

const Login = (props) => {
  const { handleSubmit } = props
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <h3>Login</h3>
      <button>Login</button>
    </form>
  )
}

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'login',
  onSubmit: login
})(Login)



//create_action
export const createAction = (type, payload) => {
  return {
    type,
    payload
  }
}
```

I haven't had any problems dispatching actions using this approach in other components. I must just have something configured wrong with redux, but I feel like I'm doing it just as the examples described.

If I pass the login function down in props and pass it to `handleSubmit` like this

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(() => {login()})}>
```

The `onSubmit` function is called, but it's called before `SET_SUBMIT_SUCCEEDED` which makes me think that any validation I add wouldn't work, and it would submit anyway.

Comment: Could you show which actions are being dispatched and in what order. The output from redux-devtools would be great. Additionally, where does `SET_SUBMIT_SUCCEEDED` come from?

Comment: After clicking the button, two actions are being dispatched, redux-form/TOUCH and redux-form/SET_SUBMIT_SUCCEEDED in that order. None of my LOGIN_xxx actions are being dispatched.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that your `login` function should have a different signature.

From looking at the docs http://redux-form.com/6.2.0/docs/api/ReduxForm.md/

> onSubmit will be called with the following parameters:
>
> **values : Object** The field values in the form of { field1: 'value1', field2: 'value2' }.
>
> **dispatch : Function** The Redux dispatch function.
>
> **props : Object** The props passed into your decorated component.

Try something like:

```
const login = ({dispatch}) => {
  dispatch(createAction(LOGIN_REQUEST))
  return postJson('/login')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data =>
      dispatch(createAction(LOGIN_SUCCESS, { data }))
    )
    .catch(error => dispatch(createAction(LOGIN_ERROR, { error })))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This worked

```
const login = (values, dispatch) => {
  dispatch(createAction(LOGIN_REQUEST))
  return postJson('/login')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data =>
      dispatch(createAction(LOGIN_SUCCESS, { data }))
    )
    .catch(error => dispatch(createAction(LOGIN_ERROR, { error })))
}
```

Comment: This has the same effect - I just used destructuring :)
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment